# How to set ConnectionLimit for a HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, connection, httpwebrequest

I am working on a **MultiThreadingDownloader** project. So I need to send request to a URL more than one at the same time with different ranges. I know `WebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit` sets the limit of the connection. But is it enough to set it once or do we need to set it in every partial request?

I am currently using it like:

```
    HttpWebResponse SendRequest(string url, int from, int to)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.AddRange(from, to);

        //This is done in every method call. 
        //Does it makes N * 20 for N request or stay the same?
        req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 20;

        return req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        SendRequest(0, 140, url);
        SendRequest(141, 281, url);
        SendRequest(282, 422, url);
        //...20 times call...
    }
```

I am curious about does it work if I use it once for the same url?

I mean:

```
    bool limitset = false;

    HttpWebResponse SendRequest(string url, int from, int to)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.AddRange(from, to);

        //This is done in every method call. 
        //Does it makes N * 20 for N request or stay the same?
        if (!limitset)
        {
            req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 20;
            limitset = true;
        }

        return req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

Comment: *I am curious...* Then try once and check yourself

Comment: I was expecting this comment. You are right, I should try it. But my code is so complex to try it now and I need to make many changes on. And the main reason for me to ask this question, learning it with a briefing explaination.